# asynchronous event in lifecycle hooks

Tags: angular

I have a question about the asynchronous events (such as Observable events) in the lifecycle hooks.

If I have to fetch data from backend in ngOnInit, and then assign the property in the class, such as:

```
   data: string;

   ngOnInit() {
     this.httpService.get(...).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
   }
   
   ngAfgerViewInit() {}
```

Here, because Observable do callback function, which will be treated as event, and will go to event stacks queue. So my question is when the ngAfterViewInit() hook will be executed?

1. after finishing data assignment, then go to next lifecycle hook.
2. keep going to finish all lifecycle hooks, then do data assignment.

Which one is correct?

---

I did several experiments. Please see the details below.
BTW, I use ngrx store's select to create observable here.

## 1. I console to see the sequence of execution.

my code is:

[image]

the console is:

[image]

the call back function is executed as synchronous, but not executed after ngAfterViewInit.

## 2. I add another ngrx operator "of" to create another Observable in ngOnInit.

the code is:

[image]

the console is:

[image]

it is the same as #1, the call back function is executed before ngAfterViewInit, like as synchronous.

## 3. I add another ngrx operator "timer" to create another Observable in ngOnInit.

the code is:

[image]

the console is:

[image]

this time the call back function is executed after ngAfterViewInit, and treated as asynchronous.

So this make me very confused. Some Observable is treated as asynchronous, but some treated as synchronous. Somebody know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Angular source code, the *exection of hooks is a synchronous process*. It means that all hooks are placed into the **callstack** and executed one by one immediately.

Creation of subscription will be invoked inside **callstack** as well `this.httpService.get(...).subscribe(...);`.

#### Async nature of HTTP requests

`HttpClient` uses `XMLHttpRequest` under the hood with code `xhr.addEventListener('load', onLoad);`. `onLoad` - is internal callback placed into callback queue and executed after request is completed and callstack is became empty. This callback completes an observable with HTTP request and it leads to the execution of callback from `.subscribe(...)`.

So callback `.subscribe(data => this.data = data)` is placed into callstack only after angular handles async response of http request - after all hooks.

*(Btw callbacks executed synchronously for streams with sync data (e.g. `of(true).subscribe(...)`))*

**Regarding to your question, the execution order is `ngOnInit -> ngAfterViewInit -> callback function`.**

But if observable has sync data e.g. `of(true).subscribe(some_callback)` - it will be executed with order `ngOnInit -> callback -> ngAfterViewInit` - everything syncronously.

Example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdwnle

I hope it helps.

Comment: I agree with you. However, it looks like not right. Please see my post below.

Comment: My answer is correct because HTTP callback is placed into the queue - it is asynchronous. And the question was about HTTP callback. If an observable stream is running sync code -> subscription is executed synchronously e.g. `of(true).subscribe(data => console.log(data))`. In my stackblitz you can just comment a line with `delay(0)` - and see the same. But it does not change the concept that hooks are executed synchronously. I've edited my answer to make it more clear. Thanks for your note.

Comment: Your answer seems conflicted itself. You mentioned "...callback is placed into callback queue..." which means it will be called after all synchronous stacks are empty. However, if you look at my #1, #2 experiments, all callback functions in subscribe() are executed as synchronous, not put into callback queue that should be executed after the stack is empty. Furthermore, in my #3 experiment, callback function in timer's subscribe() is treated as asynchronous that is put into callback queue, because you can see the console after ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: How to explain the same kind of Observable, but some of them (of() operator) are treated as synchronous, but some of them(timer()) are treated as asynchronous?

Comment: I've updated an answer with an explanation of how HTTP requests work. About sync/async observables: if data stream has async nature (HTTP requests, delays, intervals, etc) - their callbacks are moved into callstack from the queue. Otherwise they executed synchronously.

Comment: this is very helpful. However, how do you know the observable is synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: Here is a good doc about sync/async execution in rxjs https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/scheduler.

Comment: Posting images of code is not allowed on SO. Do not answer questions that do so. This question will eventually be deleted, along with your answer. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Use ChangeDetectorRef to call next lyfecycle hook:

```
  constructor(
    private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private httpService: YourHttpService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpService.get(...).subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
      this._cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand your meaning. My question is whether the asynchronous need to be finished. and then go to the next hook. Or finish the hooks and then deal with the asynchronous requests. Which one is the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

All the events are asynchronous

It calls your get method from service then calls code in oninit outside subscribe.And once oninit is over(data still loading and inside subscribe not executed till now) afterViewInit is executed.

And in between whenever data arrives from service your subscribe gets executed

check below link for more
https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3071-synchronous-vs-asynchronous-eventemitters-in-angular-2-beta-14.htm